# pip error after upgrading pip & scrapy by "pip install --upgrade"

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

Using debian 8(jessie) amd64 with python 2.7.9. I tried following commands:

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip install --upgrade scrapy
```

after that, I am getting following pip error

```
root@debian:~# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 567, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2604, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2264, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2270, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip.download import path_to_url
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 39, in <module>
from pip._vendor import requests, six
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 54, in <module>
import OpenSSL.SSL
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
from OpenSSL._util import (
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 4, in <module>
binding = Binding()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 89, in __init__
self._ensure_ffi_initialized()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 113, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
libraries=libraries,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 80, in build_ffi
extra_link_args=extra_link_args,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.py", line 437, in verify
lib = self.verifier.load_library()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 114, in load_library
return self._load_library()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 225, in _load_library
return self._vengine.load_library()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/vengine_cpy.py", line 174, in load_library
lst = list(map(self.ffi._get_cached_btype, lst))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.py", line 409, in _get_cached_btype
BType = type.get_cached_btype(self, finishlist)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/model.py", line 61, in get_cached_btype
BType = self.build_backend_type(ffi, finishlist)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/model.py", line 507, in build_backend_type
base_btype = self.build_baseinttype(ffi, finishlist)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/model.py", line 525, in build_baseinttype
% self._get_c_name())
cffi.api.CDefError: 'point_conversion_form_t' has no values explicitly defined: refusing to guess which integer type it is meant to be (unsigned/signed, int/long)
```

googled for several similar problem, cffi or cryptography may cause this problem, but i can't find any clear way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the exact same error today, but in a different situation. I suspect this is related to `cryptography` module.

What helped me was to install a specific version of `cffi` package:

```
pip install cffi==1.7.0
```

Comment: I cannot install that because I cannot even run pip command without getting that error. Any solution?

Comment: I forced remove cffi from site-packages and install version 1.7.0 from pip. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

i removed cffi and tried this command to install cffi 1.7.0:

```
pip install cffi==1.7.0
```

it worked, thank you, alecxe and moeseth :)

Answer (score 0):

My situation was like @alecxe

This works:

```
pip install cffi==1.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as *moeseth*: the `pip install something` answers are pretty useless when all pip commands throw the original exception. Installing cffi v. 1.7.0 also solved the problem and this is how I managed to do it in Debian Jessie without relying on pip:

1. Temporarily add testing repos to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, e.g.,

   ```
   deb http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
   ```
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Use aptitude or apt-get to upgrade `python-cffi` and `python-cffi-backend` to v. 1.7.0
4. Remove the lines added in step 1. from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

So I was in a situation where `pip` was failing. I had to remove `python-cffi` and then install it from pip with a correct version

```
sudo apt-get remove python-cffi
pip install cffi==1.7.0
```

Works like a charm.